# How do you make table cell content-width with selects and textboxes?

Tags: html, css

I have a table column that can contain selects or inputs (type text). I want the width of the column to equal the width of the widest item. I also want all of the selects to equal that width. I've been trying to set widths with css in different combinations of auto, 100% but can't get it to work.

Comment: please post your code with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the vague question. I found the solution, which was just add this to the css:

```
        input[type='text'] {
            width: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
        }
        select {
            width: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
        }
```

This makes the width of the columns the width of the widest content, and also keeps a scroll bar in the container when you resize it. It also makes all selects the same width.

Comment: adding width: auto to my select's style fixed my issue as well, where the table column with selects was too narrow and was cropping the selects.